# Why is Java disabled in Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome

Why is Java disabled in Chrome? Is it some security concern?

From the official [Java website](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml):

> **Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)**
>   The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin architecture NPAPI, which has been supported by all major web browsers for over a decade. Google's Chrome version 45 (scheduled for release in September 2015) drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins for Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based plugins.

But does anyone know why? How could it be dangerous for Chrome users with the latest version of the Java JRE installed?